# 'email has been sent' massage is shown email is not receiving in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, codeigniter-2

i have use CodeIgniter 2.2.6

i am trying  to sent email but i can't get error and not received email

```
<?php   
      class email_otp_demo extends CI_Controller
      {
           public function index()
      {
           $this->load->library('email');
           $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smpt',
            'mailpath' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail,
            //'mailpath' => 'www.google.com', also try
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            //'smtp_port' => 456, also try
            'smtp_user' => 'my.email@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword', 
            'smtp_timeout'=>50,
            'mailtype' => 'text',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE,
            'newline' =>'\r\n'
           );
        //    glnlwboynexfjqxj
     $this->email->initialize($config);
    
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->set_crlf("\r\n");        
    $this->email->from('my.email@gmail.com', 'Social media website');
    $this->email->to('sender@yahoo.com');
    //$this->email->to('sender@gmail.com'); also try this
     
    // $this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
    // $this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');
        
    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
        
    echo $this->email->send();
        echo "<hr>";
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    
}

 }

 ?>
```

i have get following output but not received email

```
    1
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Sun, 4 Dec 2022 16:53:27 +0530
From: "Social media website" <renish.batada@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <renish.batada@gmail.com>
Reply-To: "renish.batada@gmail.com" <renish.batada@gmail.com>
X-Sender: renish.batada@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <638c832f6b8c0@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?iso-8859-1?Q?Email_Test?=
Testing the email class.
```

i have also try to enable and disable to step verification
but not received email

i use app password  and original password but not workworking